# Node.js "require" - what does it do exactly and how?

Tags: node.js

I currently have two scripts. The first script collects a bunch of data and puts it in a table for export:

```
exports.bigDataTable = dataTable;
```

The second script requires this data like so:

```
refinedDataTable = require('./script1.js').bigDataTable;
```

What is actually happening when these lines are executed? Does `exports` make that data available for anyone who wants it, even if they didn't specifically request it? Or does only the script executing `require` get the data?

At the same time, does running `require` actually execute the entire script that the data is being required from? Or does it only get the data being exported provided the script exporting the data has previously been run?

My problem is that the data generating script has a setInterval section that basically repeatedly updates dataTable over time. The second script that uses this data also uses setInterval to update it's copy of the dataTable. I think I'm having issues with conflicting updates and reads, but need to understand what `exports` and `require` actually do.

Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can read "Node js in Action"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exports` is the "returned" object at the end of your file. In fact, the real variable is `module.exports`. This is why you have to write `module.exports = something;`. Because `exports = something;` will not change the `module.exports` variable.

When you use `require('file.js')`, `file.js` is executed and it returns the `module.exports` variable. This value is cached. The next time you call `require('file.js')`, you'll get the same object. `file.js` is not executed again.

Keep in mind that this is the exact same object with the same reference:

```
var a = require('test.js');
a.foo = 42;
console.log(a.foo); // 42

var b = require('test.js');
b.foo = 30;

console.log(b.foo); // 30
console.log(a.foo); // 30
```

You can find the detailed documentation on `require` and modules [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: This explains some of the behavior I've seen in my experimenting, but I will have to read and experiment a bit more. There are clearly problems elsewhere in my code at the moment haha. Thanks!